# How to get the 'about' section of a Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

This is my code, but I get 'about is not defined':

```
FB.api(
"/barackobama?fields=about",
function (response) {
  if (response && !response.error) {
    console.log(about); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=barackobama%3Ffields%3Dabout&version=v2.5

Maybe try with the correct syntax:

```
FB.api('/barackobama', {fields: 'about'}, function(response) {
    ...
}
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api

Comment: done but doesn't work. Maybe do I need to pass the access token ?

Comment: usually, the javascript sdk takes care of that. although, if the page is restricted, you would need to login (with FB.login) first, because in that case you would need a user token.